# THREE JS: loading large model crashes browser

Tags: three.js, loader, ply-file-format

If I load a small PLY file (4-10 MB) using the following code:

```
this.loader.load('assets/data/GuyFawkesMask.ply', function (geometry) {
      var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );

      console.log(bufferGeometry);

      // Create object
        let object =
            new THREE.Mesh(bufferGeometry,
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
                {
                    color: 0xFFFFFF,
                    //vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
                    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
                    shininess: 0
                })
            );

        _this.add(object);
    });
```

Everything works fine.

If I load large files 50MB+ the Browser sometime crashes or if the model is loaded successfully the interaction with the object using the orbit-control is painfully slow in some computer.

I appreciate that 3D models are complex beasts but do you know if there are ways to optimize memory usage, model loading in THREE js without decimate the file, operation that I cannot do without losing vital information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue with larger models. What I suggest is that you stream and load the model in small chunks (for example 1mb at a time).
The problem is, Three.js does not support loading chunked models.
What I did for myself was to rewrite a loader to work on chunks of data and build the internal representation from chunks.

Another way would be to export the scene in smaller pieces and then recombine them after loading.

There is also the third possibility, that the model is simply very complex.

Edit: Okay, I played around a bit and if you convert the file into a binary STL, then it works a bit better and does not crash chrome, while maintaining the same vertex count.
I'll include a link here to 2 converted files, where one is a decimated version (70% reduction in vertex count) and the other is a conversion of the original, both of them worked for me.

Comment: Hi Eerik, this post is not 5 years old :) It is very recent. I am not an expert in Three JS and your idea of exporting the scene in smaller pieces and then recombine them after loading sounds good. The problem is I do not know where to start :( I have also noted that the app chrashes in Chrome but not in Firefox. In Firefox I can see the following warning: "THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex WARNING: 0:1: ...... "extension 'GL_ARB_gpu_shader5' is not supported". I wonder if this is the problem in Chrome but a Google search did not provide useful clues so far..

Comment: I guess I was sleepy and took the number "12" to mean 2012 not April 12 :)
Can you link me the model you are having problems with so I can give it a try?

Comment: I can take a look later in the day, will get back to you.

Comment: Alright, I took a look and your problem is relatively simple. You have way too much detail. Basically you have like 1.7 million vertices 3m+ faces and so on. You said you can't use the decimate modifier without losing too much information. Why do you need so much detail if I may ask?

Comment: If performance and memory usage aren't critical, then the first problem you run into with Chrome is the maximum heap size. Basically the javascript Virtual Machine will not let you allocate more than about 1.7GB of memory. So for that reason alone, it would make sense to load a smaller model or somehow stream it.

Comment: Thank you Eerik, I really appreciate your help. i will try to use meshLab to reduce the details. Are you familiar with decimation and meshlab. Can I be rude and use a bit more of your time asking if you can recommend some good settings for a decimation that does not compromise quality too much?

Comment: What I did was to import the .ply file into blender, select the mesh, then apply a decimation modifier with 0.3 as the ratio. You can find an example here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8976
If it helped, could mark my response as the correct answer as well.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much for your help.Really appreciated.